# update dataTables after adding raw html for a row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm adding a row to my table by passing raw html since I need some [data-] values in a couple of cells.

and I want that DataTables updates after this insertion, but I can't find how to do that.

I'm globally activating any table that has the class

```
$('.dataTable').DataTable(options);
```

then at some point I will add some row to a specific table:

```
let dataRow = '<tr data-bmid="' + j.id + '">';
dataRow = dataRow + '<td class="bmtitle">' + j.title + '</td>';
dataRow = dataRow + '<td data-color="'+j.colorCode+'">"+j.colorName + "</td>";
dataRow = dataRow + '</tr>';
$('#myTable tbody').append(dataRow);
```

I've tried:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable().draw();


$('#myTable').dataTable().update();


let dt = oTable.dataTable().api();
dt.row.add(dataRow);
dt.draw();
```

Hope you can help me find a solution to this

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it.

the code is:

```
let dt = oTable.dataTable().api();
dt.row.add($(dataRow));
dt.draw();
```

I had been pretty close, all I was missing was enclose the html I had created in a jquery call: `dataRow` to `$(dataRow)`

Thanks to everybody

Comment: Cheers, for answering your own question

Comment: I was looking for this answer for answers! Thank you for posting. I only found how to add a row with raw data, but I had just as you a row with many custom HTML elements in it. You saved me a ton of time :-).